# how to remove object from array of rm mapper library in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
array1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] rm_customObjectForKey:@"cart"];
    for (NSData *encodedObject in array1) {
        myCartObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject];

        [arrCod addObject:myCartObject.ProdCode];
        [arrNam addObject:myCartObject.ProdName];
        [arrQty addObject:myCartObject.Quantity];
        [arrPrc addObject:myCartObject.Price];
        [arrImg addObject:myCartObject.Image];
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I used this code to add object and it's work fine for me, now i want to remove this object from button click event.
then how to do this?

can anyone solve my problem ?
thanks in advance...

Comment: So which entry do you want to delete?

Comment: @Droppy at selected indexpath

Comment: code added in comment @NilamPari

Comment: just read out array, modify it and write it back to nsuserdefault with same key

Comment: @NilamPari you done with this ?? or still there is issue

Comment: @ravi.p still getting issues

Comment: i Have added code in my answer have you tried it? or just tell me which object you want to remove ?

Comment: @ravi.p I have use your code and it deletes all data but i want to delete only one object value from rm mapper library object

Comment: no i m asking about this code                                                                                     
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; NSMutableArray *arrCartData = [defaults rm_customObjectForKey:@"cart"]; [arrCartData removeObjectAtIndex:1]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just add this code where you want to remove and after that just synchronize it. and you are done.

**CODE**

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"cart"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: it deletes all values from array

Comment: i want to delete only specific value from array

Comment: so do one thing get all data from user default to array and remove that specific index from array and save again that object.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            NSMutableArray *arrCartData = [defaults rm_customObjectForKey:@"cart"];
            [arrCartData removeObjectAtIndex:1];                   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`[NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutablearray/1416616-removeobjectatindex?language=objc):

```
NSUInteger index = [indexPath row];

[arrCod removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[arrNam removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[arrQty removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[arrPrc removeObjectAtIndex:index];
[arrImg removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

then refresh your tableview using `reloadData`, however using:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                 withRowAnimation:YES];
```

will give a better user experience.